# dispatch a action once server side validation passed in redux form

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk, react-router-redux

I have facing a problem in redux form , my issue is in code,  once i pass my server validation. I want to dispatch a action, but i couldn't make it,
i am using redux form's [submit validations example](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/submitValidation/) approach, in my form i have both the client & server side validation.

#### LoginForm.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

import { required, email, maxLength25 } from '../utils/validations';
import validate from '../utils/signup_validate';
import { renderField } from '../utils/textFieldGroup';
import { login } from '../actions/submit';

const LoginForm =(props) => {
        const { handleSubmit, submitSucceeded, error } = props

        return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(login)}>
            <div className={typeof error!='undefined'?'show alert alert-danger': 'hidden'}>
             <strong>Error!</strong> {error}
            </div>
            <Field name="email" type="text"
              component={renderField} label="Email"
              validate={[ required, email, maxLength25 ]}
            />
            <Field name="password" type="password"
              component={renderField} label="Password"
              validate={[ required, maxLength25 ]}
            />
            <p>
              <button type="submit" disabled={submitSucceeded} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
            </p>
          </form>
        )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'loginForm', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate
})(LoginForm)
```

#### submit.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form'
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import setAuthorizationsToken from '../utils/setAuthorizationsToken';
import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from '../utils/types';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export function login(data){
    console.log('submit', data);
    return axios.post('api/auth/login', data)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('response', response.data.token);
        const token = response.data.token
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token)
        setAuthorizationsToken(token)
        store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwt.decode(localStorage.jwtToken)))
        browserHistory.push('/');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error.response);
        throw new SubmissionError({ _error: error.response.data.errors});
    })
}

function setCurrentUser(user) {
    console.log('setCurrentUser');
    return {
        type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
        user: user
    }
}
```

i want to dispatch the setCurrentUser function so that i can set the user data in redux store.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: redux is designed for state management , not for APIs calls .. For API, best practices is to use SUB/PUB pattern ... try [mufa](https://abdennour.github.io/mufa) , you find [here](https://github.com/abdennour/mufa/tree/master/sample-site) a sample of react+mufa

Comment: for managing api calls i used the axios library, i facing issue in updating redux store. thanks for your response :)

Comment: I can help you to setup `mufa`.. let me know .. .skype: abdennour.tm .. anyway, documentation [here](https://abdennour.github.io/mufa) , sample [here](https://github.com/abdennour/mufa/tree/master/sample-site)

Comment: sure, thanks buddy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Instead of passing directly your login function to the `handleSubmit`, you can pass anonther function that does:

```
login(data).then((user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user))
```

For this to work, you need to use `connect` from `react-redux` to allow your component access to the `dispatch` function of the redux store. Also, you need to return the user from the `resolve` branch of the ajax call:

```
.then((response) => {
    console.log('response', response.data.token);
    const token = response.data.token
    localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token)
    setAuthorizationsToken(token)
    return jwt.decode(localStorage.jwtToken));
})
```

Also, my advice is to move the `browserHistory.push('/')` call to the component (after dispatching the `setCurrentUser` action)

**Solution 2**

You actually need to chain actions together, login -> then -> setCurrentUser. For this you should use a redux middleware. If you haven't worked with middlewares before I suggest starting with `redux-thunk`: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk. With `redux-thunk` you can use the `dispatch` function inside your action creators to dispatch multiple actions. If you want more info on this, drop a comment below and I'll try to expand my answer.

Comment: Thanks @alex for replying, yes i already used the redux-thunk, but still i couldn't send the action from action creator. Please explain more.

Comment: i assumed that by using 
login(data).then((user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)), 
you want me to use HOC. currently i am using LoginPage container on which i use the LoginForm presentations component, same like below.
http://codepen.io/mglrahul/pen/apWLEa?editors=0010

Comment: @RahulMangal your container component looks ok, in order to go with solution 1, you need to map your `setCurrentUser` to the props in `mapDispatchToProps` and call it on the `then()` function of the `login`

Comment: i did as you say but i go the error, pls take a look the code.
http://codepen.io/mglrahul/pen/apWLEa?editors=0010

Comment: `setCurrentUser` needs to be in the mapDispatchToProps part, you need to import it from your action creators file and use it in the map object (second argument of connect). As for the login function itself, it seems like it's not related to redux in any way, so you don't need to dispatch it or map it through connect. Simply invoke it when you need it and when the promise fulfils, you dispatch your `setCurrentUser`. Unfortunately I don't have time to write the full snippet, just drop a line and I'll be back later.

Comment: i still couldn't make it out, Please show the code when you have some time, thanks for everything :)